# File Info PHP Error - Class 'finfo' not found but the module is in php.ini

Tags: php, php-extension, fileinfo

I am having a problem getting File Info working.  It is enabled in PHP.ini but when I run a php -m it is not listed.  I have PHP 5.5 so it should be standard and not need the pecl.  I am a newbie and confused so please be kind.

```
php -m

[PHP Modules]
bcmath
calendar
Core
ctype
curl
date
dom
ereg
exif
filter
ftp
gd
gettext
hash
iconv
imagick
imap
ionCube Loader
json
libxml
mbstring
mcrypt
mysql
openssl
pcre
Phar
posix
Reflection
session
SimpleXML
sockets
SPL
sqlite3
standard
tokenizer
XCache
XCache Cacher
xml
xmlreader
xmlwriter
zip
zlib

[Zend Modules]
XCache
XCache Cacher
the ionCube PHP Loader
```

In my PHP.ini

```
extension = "fileinfo.so"
```

Comment: Check what `php.ini` is actually used. It might not be the one you think.

Comment: I think you should locate the right php.ini try running php --ini

Comment: By default this extension gets built in to PHP since 5.3, there is no `so` file you need to load.  Did you build PHP yourself or install from a package manager?  Does the output of the `configure command` in your PHP info show `--disable-fileinfo` which would disable it from being included with PHP in which case you would need to compile and install the PECL module.

Comment: Yes, thanks.  Needed to be recompiled with FileInfo enabled!

Comment: @Chris Glad that was it.  I added it as an answer so it may be easier for people to find in the future.

Comment: Enable `php_fileinfo.dll` in `php.ini` and restart your server.

Comment: https://github.com/brandonsavage/Upload/issues/69#issuecomment-326731455

Answer (score 6):

By default this extension gets built in to PHP since 5.3, meaning there is no `so` to load.

Since it is not showing as an available module, it may mean PHP was compiled with the `--disable-fileinfo` switch (look at the Configure Command output in phpinfo) which would disable it from being included with PHP.

If it was compiled with the disable finfo option, you will either need to recompile PHP without that option, or compile and install the PECL module and then dynamically load the extension in php.ini.

Comment: how to compile and install it with PECL module? when I update or install PHP it just simply install it and do not give me any option to selection extensions. but I am having PECL module it is shoing file_infopath is the same module?

Comment: Ok, installed CodeGen_PECL module via PEAR now I want to know how to dynamically load it into php.ini

Answer (score 4):

I had same error as the OP on a cPanel host. The solution was to go into my web hosting control panel, select "Select PHP Version" and then enable the "fileinfo" extension.

Answer (score 2):

This was my solution using WHM on Cpanel

1. Log into WHM as root and search ‘easy‘ into the search field in the top left of WHM.
2. click on EasyApache 4. software
3. In the Currently Installed Packages section, click on the Customize button.
4. In the Search field, type to enter ‘fileinfo‘.Click the toggle button(s) next to the PHP version(s) that you would like the PHP extension installed for.
5. Click the Review option from the left.
6. Confirm the options you selected are listed under the “Please review the following list of packages you are about to install by provisioning this profile.” section. Then, click the Provision button.
7. Once the installation is completed, you will receive a message: “The provisioning process is complete”. Click the Done button to finish.

Comment: This worked for me after a server migration. MODX wouldn't display but the manager would. Thanks!

Comment: Welcome @GarethWyn

Answer (score 1):

Just go to "Select PHP Version" in your cPanel and then go to "Extensions", search for "fileinfo", and then finally enable this feature and this will probably fix your problem like it did mine.

Comment: Hi Daniel You are assuming the OP has CPanel and this may not be the case. But, well, your answer can be helpful for future searchers with CPanel installed... Anyway, just a quick question: Did you note that this post is more than 6 years old? I think your collaboration will be more appreciated in recent posts, where there are more chances that the OP is still facing the issue. Thanks for collaborating with the community and welcome to Stackoverflow.

Comment: Helped me on cpanel

Answer (score 0):

I encountered this problem in Laravel.

There are two solutions, both work:

1. Import the class

   ```
    use finfo;

    $finfo = new finfo(FILEINFO_MIME_TYPE);
   ```
2. Or put a leading `\` if using a global class inside a namespace.

   ```
    $finfo = new \finfo(FILEINFO_MIME_TYPE);
   ```

Comment: where do I do this?